# Migrating from SVN to GIT with all externals

Tags: svn, git

I have a standard SVN repo with 4 SVN externals

I want to migrate it into a GIT repo without submodules (simply add the externals into my repo), and say "bye" to SVN

What is the best options on a Linux box to do it ?

I have created an authors.txt file

I have played with git-svn and svn2git from Github, but without success until yet.

Comment: How do you intend to keep the contents of the externals up-to-date if you're not using submodules?

Comment: They should be threated as the rest, simply files of the project

Answer (score 0):

In [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6517495/279564) you can find a nice set of steps to move from subversion to git including project renames.
It doesn't take into account the externals, but might be a good place to start.

PS: I'm in the same situation as yourself... I was hoping someone would have answered to your question :-(